# MonoGame Platform Agnostic Input/Output

Tags: user-interface, xna, monogame, multiplatform

I've done a bit of XNA work, and I'm now trying to work in MonoGame. Previously, for all my input and output needs, I used `Microsoft.Xna.Framework`. I'm now trying to make one version of my game to deploy on as many platforms as possible (excluding, at the moment, touch interfaces), but I don't know what I should be doing regarding the mouse, for example.

Does MonoGame make `Microsoft.Xna.Framework` platform-agnostic or do I have to use other frameworks and switch between them depending on the platform?

Comment: I think the best way to know this is to try.

Comment: I don't have other platforms on which to test. I only have a Windows PC at the moment, and it would be really nice to not have to try out all possible frameworks on ten different platforms.

Comment: @pinckerman I disagree. The best way to learn something is to ask, otherwise you'd spend all your time doing things just to find out they don't work when someone could have told you the answer in very little time.

Comment: @craftworkgames I think that practice can always teach us something, so I prefer to try before asking. In this case he clearly can't actually try what he is asking, but I didn't know that.

Comment: @pinckerman Yeah, I agree that trying something before asking is generally a good idea (especially on stackoverflow) but it will only get you so far, you can learn a lot very quickly by leveraging other people's experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MonoGame is designed to make it easy to port your game to other platforms, you shouldn't need to use any other frameworks to achieve that goal. However, it's not as simple as simply recompiling the code for each new platform.

For the most part all of your code will remain the same, but you'll need to put together a project for each platform and link all of the code files in each one. I won't go into detail about this, but I'll just say that you can do it and it's not that difficult.

Now, what you will find is that you may have to write some platform specific code to handle device specific stuff like screen scaling and input handling. What exactly you need to do will depend on your game, so I can't really explain that in detail either.

To make your life easier, it can be helpful to think about how your game is going to work on other platforms and write your code accordingly. For example, a touch on mobile device is very similar to the click of a mouse so you could wrap this functionality in a method of your own to minimize the code changes required when porting. On the other hand, some things you can do with a mouse simply don't work on touch interfaces, like right click, and hover. Similarly, touch interfaces have [commonly used gestures](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/gestures.html) that don't really map to a mouse on a PC like long press, swipe and pinch.

So the short answer is, you don't HAVE to do anything special, but you should at least think about it if you plan to port your game in the future.

Comment: Thank you very much. My question, in my particular instance, is regarding the PC platforms (Linux vs. Mac vs. Windows), regarding more specifically input and graphics. It seems as though I'm using a lot of Microsoft frameworks, while there are OpenTK alternatives (which I can't get to work for some reason). I'm unsure if I should be attempting to use the OpenTK alternatives or if the Microsoft frameworks will compile okay.

Comment: Even though OpenTK comes with MonoGame, you shouldn't need to use it directly. MonoGame's job is to hide the implementation details of the specific platform so you can make games work with mostly the same code. In an ideal world, you could take a game made with Microsoft XNA and recompile it with MonoGame without any changes. In reality it's slightly more complicated, but not much.